# Filtering an Angular ng-repeat with “track by” by a boolean property

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

```
$scope.users = [{
  "firstname": "Steve",
  "lastname": "Jobs",
  "id": 1,
  "userLog": {
    "id": 1,
    "userId": "Steve01",
    "enabled": true
  }
}, {
  "firstname": "Michelle",
  "lastname": "Jobs",
  "id": 2,
  "userLog": {
    "id": 2,
    "userId": "Michelle02",
    "enabled": false
  }
}];
```

```html
<div ng-repeat="user in users|  filter: { enabled: true } track by user.userLog.id ">
```

Help me how to filter if enabled is true the user details will display else hide.

Thanks

Comment: you can use ng-if

<div ng-repeat="user in users|  track by user.userLog.id " ng-if="user.userLog.enabled">

Comment: enabled is nested so you should change it like this:
filter: { userLog.enabled: true }

Answer (score 2):

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users|  filter: { userLog.enabled: true } track by user.userLog.id ">
```

Answer (score 0):

**Js**

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users | filter: {userLog :{enabled:true}}">
    {{user.firstname}}
</div>
```

**Example**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.users = [{
    "firstname": "Steve",
    "lastname": "Jobs",
    "id": 1,
    "userLog": {
      "id": 1,
      "userId": "Steve01",
      "enabled": true
    }
  }, {
    "firstname": "Michelle",
    "lastname": "Jobs",
    "id": 2,
    "userLog": {
      "id": 2,
      "userId": "Michelle02",
      "enabled": false
    }
  }];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <div ng-repeat="user in users | filter: {userLog :{enabled:true}}">
    {{user.firstname}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users |  filter: (!user.userLog.enabled || '') track by user.userLog.id">
```